# Why was the gadgets site merged into this one?

Tags: discussion, osx, ios

I have a feeling this will be somewhat controversial, but to be perfectly frank it seems like the Apple.SE site and the community that was forming around it was quite OS X centered.  Now with the huge influx of iOS related questions, the site seems disjointed and less focused.

Personal opinion: A lot of OS X users don't have much interest in iphone or ipod, and generally ignore these questions, but it's hard when so many are suddenly about these devices.

Why did the sites need to be merged in the first place?

Comment: +1 for wondering about merging OSX and iOS! I have an iPhone but no Mac. In my view, the iOS questions kind of drown in the OSX "noise" here. `OSX != iOS` !

Answer (score 10):

I think it was a pretty logical thing to do to migrate iPhone, iPad, and other Apple gadget questions here after the Gadgets site was [closed](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/pruning-season/). Why? **This is the only SE site where they are on-topic**.

If we go back and look at the [Apple site proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/151?phase=definition) at Area 51, there is nothing there that defines this site as "OS X only" or "OS X mostly" (although it *is* true that the top on-topic examples are Mac/OS X ones). (Also, if Apple SE actually was "Mac / OS X only", that would mean there was no need for it in the first place, as Mac and OS X are perfectly on-topic at [Super User](https://superuser.com/).)

If you consider [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), is it becoming "disjointed" with the huge influx of questions on Ruby or Python that the average C# programmer really doesn't have much interest in? By the way, [Spolsky discusses](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/merging-season/) the SE scope issue in the latest blog entry; interesting read.

Bottom line: if you don't care much about iOS related questions, you can easily ignore them. (You can tweak your prefs so that you don't even *see* those questions, if you want to.) I don't think merging in those questions does harm to the community, at least in the long run.

Comment: I 100% agree with you :D

Answer (score 2):

I believe there wasn’t much activity going on on Gadgets anyway and most were iPhones/iPods/iPads.

Comment: A lot (most?) of the questions were about Apple gear and Android gear. (Obviously, only *Apple questions* were merged here.) Reasons why they decided to close it are [detailed in the blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/pruning-season/).

Comment: @Jonik: your comment is really the true answer to this question :)